# HTML <div> still overflows even if content is way smaller

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm having a bit of a struggle with a CSS Scaled `<div>`.

I have an outer `<div>` that has fixed `width` and `height`, and an inner `<div>` that should go with the flow. The problem is that even if I scale down inner `<div>` (down to, let's say 0.3), the vertical scroll-bar on the outer `<div>` it's still visible and that's really unexpected (inspecting the inner `<div>` reveals that it is way smaller than its parent). I really think that the outer `<div>` should have no scroll-bar unless the inner `<div>` overflows.

CODE

```
<div class="outter">
<div class="inner">
    <p>Random</p>
    <div>Silly</div>
    <h2>Thing</h2>
</div>
```

```
.outter {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 300px;

    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #222;
}

.inner {
    font-size: 40px;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: scale(1.3);
    height: 200px;
}
```

I should mention that instead of inner `<div>`'s children I have an `<svg>`, `<img>` and `<canvas>` without `font-size` property, just with `width`s and `height`s that are changing according to the scaling factor.

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xL12oyg8/1/) of my problem.

Comment: Code in the question please!

Comment: I see the inner's height as 75px..And I can't use overflow hidden on the outer div because I need to zoom in and out the inner content multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `display:flex;` to the class `.outter`. Following two examples: the first with normal content and **without** a scrollbar which will not be overflow and the second example with content which will be overflow, but now with vertical scrollbar. On both examples the css is the same!

**Normal Content**

```css
.outter {
  box-shadow:0 0 2px #222;
  display:flex;
  height:200px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  width:300px;
}

.inner {
  font-size:40px;
  transform-origin:top left;
  transform:scale(0.3);
  -webkit-transform:scale(0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div class="inner"> 
    <div>Silly</div>
    <h2>Thing</h2>
    <p>Random</p>
    <div>Silly</div>
    <h2>Thing</h2>
    <p>Random</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Overflow Content**

```css
.outter {
  box-shadow:0 0 2px #222;
  display:flex;
  height:200px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  width:300px;
}

.inner {
  font-size:40px;
  transform-origin:top left;
  transform:scale(0.3);
  -webkit-transform:scale(0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div class="inner"> 
    <div>Silly</div>
    <h2>Thing</h2>
    <p>Random</p>
    <div>Silly</div>
    <h2>Thing</h2>
    <p>Random</p>
    <div>Silly</div>
    <h2>Thing</h2>
    <p>Random</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to be working in the fiddle but in my actual project is not. Instead of Silly, Random, Thing elements I have an `<img>`, `<svg>` and `<canvas>` - and I still have a vertical scroll-bar even with display: flex

Comment: can you add some of these elements to your example?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of your problem

```
.outter {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 300px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #222;
}

.inner {
    font-size: 40px;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: scale(0.3);
    height:200px;
}
```

Just remove height attribute from outter class and put it to inner class

Answer (score 0):

Your height overflow is calculated by the `font-size:40px`. 
Then you `transform` it , but the height is still the same as it would be with 40px font.

That's the reason why this happens.

Comment: What if I remove the `font-size` property?  Instead of Silly, Random, Thing elements I have an `<img>`, `<svg>` and `<canvas>` and they only have a fixed `width` and `height` which are scaled once with the inner `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

Add an inner `div` and give `height`.

```css
.outter {
overflow: auto;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px #222;
}
.wrap {
height: 160px;
}
.inner {
font-size: 40px;
transform-origin: top left;
transform: scale(0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>Random</p>
        <div>Silly</div>
        <h2>Thing</h2>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
position:absolute;
```

on the outer div, and

```
position:relative;
```

on the inner div

---

See [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czna78er/)

---

I just added above mentioned attributes: the unwanted scrollbar is gone.

You might want to try and uncomment the `lorem ipsum` paragraph - which I added as commented HTML, for testing purposes - to see the scrollbar appear, when needed.